# xslt not working when injected in xml

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT, I'm trying to transform one xml file to output another xml file, however somehow it is not working, when I inject my xsl in the xml. XML is appearing as blank when I open it in IE.

I am using the below xslt code:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://some-internal-thing/user" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <RECORDS> 
 <RECORD> 
     <xsl:for-each select="document/asset/attribute">
       <xsl:attribute name="PROP NAME"> ="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>"</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="PVAL"/> <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"/><xsl:attribute name="/PVAL"/> 
         <xsl:attribute name="/PROP"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </RECORD>
 </RECORDS>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following xslt is working, However browser not showing proper XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
 &lt;  xml version="1.0"?  &gt; 
  &lt;  RECORDS  &gt; 
  &lt;  RECORD  &gt; 
     <xsl:for-each select="document/asset/attribute">
        &lt;  PROP NAME="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>"  &gt; 
           &lt;  PVAL  &gt;  <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"/>  &lt;  /PVAL  &gt; 
          &lt;  /PROP  &gt; 
     </xsl:for-each>
  &lt; /RECORD  &gt; 
  &lt; /RECORDS  &gt; 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myxslCopy.xsl"?>
<document>
<asset id="1385567968442" type="TAISHtmlContent">
<attribute name="createdby"><string value="fwadmin"/></attribute>
<attribute name="category"><string value="g"/></attribute>
<attribute name="Publist"><array>
<integer value="1385571110545"/></array>
</attribute>
<attribute name="content"><string value="&#60;p&#62;&#13;&#10;&#9;&#38;lt;div class=&#38;quot;container&#38;quot;&#38;gt;&#38;nbsp;&#38;nbsp;&#38;lt;div class=&#38;quot;four columns&#38;quot;&#38;gt; &#38;lt;div id=&#38;quot;info&#38;quot;&#38;gt; &#38;lt;h3&#38;gt;Information&#38;lt;/h3&#38;gt; &#38;lt;ul&#38;gt; &#38;lt;li&#38;gt;&#38;lt;a href=&#38;quot;siteLink:company/aboutUs.jsp&#38;quot;&#38;gt;About 
</attribute>
<attribute name="createddate"><date value="2013-12-03 15:06:54.442"/></attribute>
<attribute name="updateddate"><date value="2013-12-03 15:09:00.422"/></attribute>
<attribute name="active"><integer value="1"/></attribute>
<attribute name="fw_uid"><string value="d651728f-fe72-4ab3-9e63-684d979f62c9"/></attribute>
</asset>
</document>
```

Required output:

```
<RECORDS> 
  <RECORD> 
    <PROP NAME="createdby"> 
      <PVAL>fwadmin</PVAL> 
    </PROP> 
    <PROP NAME="category"> 
      <PVAL>g</PVAL> 
    </PROP> 
  <RECORD> 
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: What output are you trying to generate?  The `<xsl:attribute name="PVAL"/> <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"/><xsl:attribute name="/PVAL"/>` in your XSLT makes no sense.

Comment: I am trying to have an output xml of below format,          <RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="product.name">
      <PVAL>QuickCam® Chat for Skype</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="product.category_id">
      <PVAL>577</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="product.analytics.sales_count">
      <PVAL>690</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  <RECORD>
</RECORDS>

Comment: That output bears no resemblance whatsoever to the input you have provided, as far as I can tell.  Where does that data come from?

Comment: Thanks Ian, The data is coming from Oracle webcenter sites(which is a CMS) in XML Format. I am trying to apply XSLT , so that a new xml is generated in the desired format.

Comment: I meant that the input you've provided doesn't seem to contain any of the strings that you want in your output such as "QuickCam® Chat for Skype", "product.category_id", "577", "690", etc.  If the data you need isn't there in the XML then you won't be able to get it out with XSLT.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
 &lt;  xml version="1.0"?  &gt; 
  &lt;  RECORDS  &gt; 
  &lt;  RECORD  &gt; 
     <xsl:for-each select="document/asset/attribute">
        &lt;  PROP NAME="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>"  &gt; 
        &lt;  PVAL  &gt;  <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"/>  &lt;  /PVAL  &gt; 
       &lt;  /PROP  &gt; 
  </xsl:for-each>
  &lt; /RECORD  &gt; 
  &lt; /RECORDS  &gt; 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: The above xslt is working, However, when u open this with IE, it doesnot show an XML, simply shows a text kind of file with the desired format.

Comment: yes the O/P format was just an example, dont consider data please.

Comment: This is desired O/P,                                                                  <RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="createdby">
      <PVAL>fwadmin</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="category">
      <PVAL>g</PVAL>
    </PROP>
      <RECORD>
</RECORDS>

Comment: Code examples in comments don't work very well as there's no formatting, please could you edit the question with these changes rather than putting them in comments.

Comment: Doing XML to XML transformation in the browser where the target format is some self defined XML unknown to the browser usually do not work well or at least do not result in a meaningful rendering in the browser. Usually you would use XSLT in the browser to transform XML to (X)HTML or these days maybe (X)HTML and SVG and/or MathML that the browser knows to render.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to XSLT 2.0  (Saxton 9.?.?)
Then you can use this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:user="http://some-internal-thing/user" >

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <RECORDS> 
            <RECORD>
                <xsl:for-each select="document/asset/attribute">
                    <PROP>
                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME" select="@name"></xsl:attribute>
                        <PVAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"></xsl:value-of> 
                        </PVAL>
                    </PROP>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RECORD>
        </RECORDS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you must use XSLT 1.0
Then try this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:user="http://some-internal-thing/user" >

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <RECORDS> 
            <RECORD>
                <xsl:for-each select="document/asset/attribute">
                    <PROP>
                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <PVAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string/@value"></xsl:value-of> 
                        </PVAL>
                    </PROP>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RECORD>
        </RECORDS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```